# ADFS 3.0 - Error - No strong authentication method found for the request

Tags: adfs3.0

What could be the possible reason behind the error:

```
No strong authentication method found for the request.

Stack:
Encountered error during federation passive request. 

Protocol Name: 
Saml
Relying Party: 
http://testfs/adfs/services/trust 
Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.RequestFailedException: No strong authentication method found for the request from http://testfs/adfs/services/trust.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.CheckAuthenticationOptionsForMethods(ProtocolContext context, List`1 authMethods)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)
```

ADFS is properly setup with Global authentication method as follows:

1. Extranet: Forms Authentication
2. Intranet: Windows Authentication

The error comes while accessing the following url:
https://testfs/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx

Note: This happens with Multi-factor authentication is enabled.  The MFA module is custom made by https://adfsmfa.codeplex.com

Any sort of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "This happens only when Multi-factor authentication enabled". Could you describe the configuration steps? Typically this type of error implies that either the app requested for MFA or the additional auth rules (global or per-app) kicked in and ADFS could not find a suitable MFA provider. This implies that the registration of your provider had issues.

Comment: @SamuelDMSFT Where can I verify the additional auth rules? From the ADFS manager it looks like MFA at per-app level is same as the Global configuration. Also there is only 1 MFA provider checked currently.

Answer (score 0):

The issue happened in constructor, create event source need special permission, the services account for ADFS do not have this permission.

```
if (!EventLog.SourceExists(this.EventLogSource))
    EventLog.CreateEventSource(this.EventLogSource, this.EventLogGroup);
```

I remove this 2 line and create event source in separate application. (think about at install)